# how can i use LinkedList with another class' method

Tags: java, linked-list, nodes

Client is a class which hold two int variables. 
I'd like to use my own method "add"(from linkedList class) with defualt LinkedList "queue", how can I do that

```
public abstract class ClientQueue implements CQInterface{ 

Client c;

LinkedList<Client> queue = new LinkedList<Client>();

public void enqueue(Client c){
    linkedList linkedList = new linkedList();
    queue.linkedList.add(c);
}

class linkedList{
    // reference to the head node.
    private Node head;
    private int listCount;

    // LinkedList constructor
    public linkedList()
    {
        // this is an empty list, so the reference to the head node
        // is set to a new node with no data
        head = new Node(null);
        listCount = 0;
    }

    public void add(Object data)
    {
        Node temp = new Node(data);
        Node current = head;
        while(current.getNext() != null)
        {
            current = current.getNext();
        }
        current.setNext(temp);
        listCount++;
    }
```

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to accomplish.  You need to explain what you think `queue.linkedList.add(c);` is supposed to accomplish... this makes no sense.

Comment: Also, 2 really bad ideas you've used: 1) Ignoring the naming convention for classes (UppercaseFirst LetterOfEachWord); and 2) Naming your class the same as a library class, regardless of using different letter casing.

Comment: I want to use my own add method with LinkedList queue. Now I understand the naming problem thx for telling

Comment: That is impossible by definition.  Java classes don't work that way, and it's not meaningful to wish for it to be so.  What end state are you trying to get to?

Comment: the enqueue method just want to make sure add a client into LinkedList queue, I used write in this way:
    queue.add(c);
but if I go this way, I can't make each client in queue can have relationship between each other, that was the reason why I want to declear a linkedlist class.